# How can I send output from a Linux child process to the parent?

Tags: c, linux

I execute a shell command (`cmp`) using `system()` from the parent process:

```c
system("cmp file0 file1");
```

If the 2 files are different, the cmp program writes things to the terminal. For example:

```
"000.jpg 001.jpg differ: byte 4, line 1"
```

But I need this text in a `char *string` variable in the parent process and not in the console terminal.

Comment: Use `popen()` instead of `system()`. Then you can read the standard output of the program.

Comment: `popen` and `system` are unsafe, especially if the names of `file0` or `file1` are determined at runtime. Use `fork`/`exec` with output redirection. Do you really need to capture the output of `cmp`? If you only need to check if the files differ, it is enough to look at the exit code of `cmp`.  (You may then call `cmp` with `-s` to suppress all output)